# app incompatible with Huawei ascend p7

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

my app is incompatible with Huawei ascend p7, it is not present in the compatible device list nor in the excluded devices.

This is the permissions in manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
```

How my app can be compatible with Ascend p7?

Thank you

Comment: Mention the API level (Android version) of the device you wish to run on.

Comment: Alright. How are you installing the app? If via Eclipse, post the LogCat.

Comment: The app is alrealdy published, a user segnaled the issue: he cant see the app on the store

Comment: I found this link. Maybe it helps you point in right direction. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/189028?hl=en

Comment: Also check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317166/android-app-not-showing-up-in-play-store-on-some-devices

Comment: If you do find an answer, it's a good practice to share the solution/diagnosis which worked for you.

Comment: Thank you for the links, when i found the solution i will share it

Comment: I think there are no solutions at moment: the ascend p7 is not yet supported from Google Play (https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en#H)

Comment: Post it as an answer then. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are no solutions at the moment. The `Huawei Ascend p7` is not yet supported by Google Play.

[List of supported devices.](http://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en#H)